# When I edit the listing description for Office Add-in, does it come off the store?

Tags: office-store

I would like to make some minor changes to the description of my office Add-in on the AppSource page, mainly grammatical. Would this take my App off the store while the changes are approved?

or would it keep the previous one live until it's approved?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a third-party's store policy, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit an update to an existing Office add-in on AppSource, the existing listing remains live and unchanged until the update has passed validation and is approved.